# Django URL View parameter help

Tags: django, url

I'm having some trouble trying to pass a string from a URL to the views.  My page has user pages, and if you go to site.com/username it brings up that users page.  But when I try going it says this: [invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'username'].

Here's my code:

### urls.py:

```
(r'^user/(?P<userName>[^/]+)/$', 'mischief_blog.mischief_app.views.user_view'),
```

### views.py:

```
def user_view(request, userName):
    postList = userPost.objects.filter(author=userName)
    return render_to_response('user.html', {"user": user_name, "postList": postList}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

get name from url:

```
(r'^user/(?P<userName>\w+)/$', 'mischief_blog.mischief_app.views.user_view'),
```

get user from name, then get posts from user: ([**get_object_or_404**](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404)) and ([**User**](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#users))

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

def user_view(request, userName=None):
    user = get_object_or_404(User, username=userName)
    postList = userPost.objects.filter(author=user)
    return render_to_response('user.html', {"user": user, "postList": postList}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: This won't work for me because I don't have a model 'User'.  I'm just using the built in django user system thing.

Comment: If you are using the default auth system you can just import the User model.

Comment: Oh I see, I didn't see your import statement :) sorry!

Comment: I have one further question.  When I go to someone's profile, the url is site.com/user/username.   But if I click any other link, home for example, it tries to go to site.com/user/home.    How do I fix this so that it goes to site.com/home instead?

Comment: (r^'/$', 'home', name='home') and in templates {% url home %}, sorry on my mobile. But you can post another question if it's not working.